# Creating time stamps using .format()

Tags: python

Basically in this assignment we have to create a time, based on values of ran(hour,min):. Below I will post the code I have and then the error message I receive. Is my code just really bad or there something I'm missing? What does it mean by "Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly.

```
def show_time(hour,min):
if(hour > 12):
    hour = hour -12
if(min < 10):
    min = "0"+min
print("{hour}:{min}".format(show_time()))
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zyLabsUnitTestRunner.py", line 10, in <module>
    passed = test_passed(test_passed_output_file)
  File "/home/runner/local/unit_test_student_code/zyLabsUnitTest.py", line 33, in test_passed
    ans = show_time(hour,min)
  File "/home/runner/local/unit_test_student_code/main.py", line 15, in show_time
    min = "0"+min
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
if(min<10):
    min = "0"+min
```

you are attempting to concatenate a string and an integer, which python cannot do. To convert a string to an int, use int(str), and to convert an int to a string, use str(int)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are concatenating `"0"` (a string) with `min`, which is an integer.

```
>>> '0' + 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

You would avoid this by casting `min` as a string:

```
>>> '0' + str(3)
'03'
```

The best solution, though, would be to save this kind of formatting for--you guessed it!--`str.format()`. It has a [rich syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) that allows you to keep these transformations where they belong. Here is an example:

```
>>> '{:02d}'.format(3)
'03'
```

As it stands, your code has several issues:

1. You are calling it without arguments in your code snippet.
2. You are using the variable *inside* the format function rather than in its arguments: you appear to be mixing up passing in keyword parameters like so:

```
>>> '{a}:{b}'.format(**{'a':1, 'b':2})
'1:2'
```

3. You are not returning anything with the function.
4. `min` is a bad name for a variable since it is a built-in function.

Here is a much easier way of doing everything in one block:

```
print("{}:{:02d}".format(hour % 12, minute))
```

Comment: I understand everything except {:02d}, can you explain what that does?

Answer (score 0):

I think you use format incorrectly and you cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects (min = "0"+min). I think this works:

```
def show_time(hour,min):
    if(hour > 12):
        hour = hour -12
    if(min < 10):
        min = "0" + str(min)
    print "{}:{}".format(hour, min)
```